# Any way to solve this loop on array problem i'm facing?

Tags: php

So, here is the thing.
I have to link several cities, and calculate their distance, but right now, the distance is not the point.

I have an array like this :

```
$villes=[
    "Paris",
    "London",
    "Berlin",
    "Madrid"];
```

And the output must be something like this :

```
"Paris" -> "London"
"Paris" -> "Berlin"
"Paris" -> "Madrid"
"London"-> "Paris"
"London"-> "Berlin"
"London"-> "Madrid"
"Berlin"-> "Paris"
"Berlin" -> "London"
"Berlin" -> "Madrid"
"Madrid" -> "Paris"
"Madrid" -> "London"
"Madrid" -> "Berlin"
```

Of course if there was only 4 values I would have done it myself, with my little hands, but here is 46 actually. So I need to do a loop that can allow me to do that.

I think that might be looping like 4000 times so if there is a way to optimize that, could be so cool ! Thank's a lot guys

Comment: have you got any code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$villes=["Paris","London","Berlin","Madrid"];
foreach($villes as $ville)
{
    
    foreach($villes as $ville2)
    {
      if($ville2 != $ville)
      {
        echo $ville . ' -> ' . $ville2 . '<br />';
      }
    }
}
```

You loop through it twice, if it is the same one as you have right now, you do nothing. Else you echo it (or do whatever you want with it)

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thank you so much !

Comment: No worries, that's what we're here for :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_spread(array $items): array {
    return array_reduce($items, function($spread, $item) use($items): array {
        foreach(array_diff($items, [$item]) as $otherItem) {
            $spread[] = [$item, $otherItem];
        }
        
        return $spread;
    }, []);
}

function array_sprintf(string $template, array $items): array {
    return array_map(fn(array $parts) => sprintf($template, ...$parts), $items);
}

echo implode(PHP_EOL, array_sprintf('%s -> %s', array_spread([
    "Paris",
    "London",
    "Berlin",
    "Madrid",
])));
```

https://3v4l.org/#preview